# How do I tighten this screw?

Tags: bathroom, tools

I have a fairly new bathroom suite. The toilet seat has a nifty quick-release hinge which allows you to just press two buttons to take it off for cleaning. Underneath, the hinge assembly is fixed on with a long screw, tightened with a nut that fits snugly into a recess inside the porcelain. There's no screw head accessible from underneath, and the hinge doesn't come off on top to screw from that direction.

Naturally, the seat has come loose. How do I tighten it? I've tried just turning the screw thread with a pair of pliers, but it's hard to get a decent grip and this only works for a short while. Is there a particular tool I need to buy to tighten this sort of screw? Or a particular technique?

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: Are you sure the screw heads aren't accessible under a snap-on cap?

Answer (score 9):

Two things unbelievable about my answer.

1. It's not about electrical
2. I took pictures of my toilet

I think I have the same seat, so here we go...

[image: This is what the back of my lid looks like]

Excuse the glare, but this is what holds my seat down.

[image: Clips are twisted counter-clockwise]

Now take the top half of the clips and twist them counter-clockwise.  The picture shows them all the way turned.  Now the hard part...

[image: It's off!!!]

You might have to work at this but you give it some wiggles and it pulls straight up.

Hopefully this is what you have and hopefully the artistic work I did does not go in vain.  Taking pictures of toilets or loo's or any device of this nature just does not do anything for me.  I hope they don't pull my man card, then I have to get my you know whats out of my wife's purse.

Comment: I have this same toilet seat.  These have a nut on the underside that needs to be held while you turn the screw heads.  Normally when I do toilet work, I just hold the screw head stationary and turn the nut.  Since it's all plastic pieces you only want to tighten it as much as you can do with your hand.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently replaced my toilet seat so I know exactly what you're talking about.

First things first...you just need a [Phillips screwdriver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_F._Phillips). I have a screwdriver that allows me to toggle between a small and a large screwdriver head. Use the large one.

Then check to make sure that the plastic nut for each plastic screw is sitting nicely/snugly in the recess underneath. If it isn't then when you're tightening, it may not tighten correctly so that could be the reason for the loose seat.

If the nut is not sitting in the recess, you'll need to hold the nut while you use the screwdriver to tighten until the nut seats itself in the recess (I found it easier to do the reverse...use my hand to tighten the nut until I can't turn no more because my fingers won't fit in the recess).

Give this a try.

Comment: The question specifically stated that no screw heads are visible and that's the problem.